# Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method file on channel video_thumbnail)

Tags: flutter

When i use `ImagePicker.pickVideo(source: ImageSource.camera)`  it's work perfectly but if i use `ImagePicker.pickVideo(source: ImageSource.gallery)`   i receive this error

```
Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method file on channel video_thumbnail)
```

```
getVideo() async {
    final pickedFile = await ImagePicker.pickVideo(source: ImageSource.gallery);

    if(pickedFile != null){
      videoAddress = pickedFile.path;

      final thumbnailPath = await VideoThumbnail.thumbnailFile(
          video: videoAddress,
          imageFormat: ImageFormat.JPEG,
          quality: 75);

      videoPosterAddress = thumbnailPath;
      setState(() { videoPoster = File(thumbnailPath); });
    }
  }
```

videoPoster contain thumbnail file.

Comment: I am facing same issue any idea ?